# Javascript Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

i get a Unexpected token {  error on this line

```
var isSplash =true;
//------DocReady-------------
--->    $(document).ready{(function()};
 if(location.hash.length == 0)
    location.hash="!/"+$('#content > ul > li').eq(2).attr('id');
```

Comment: How is this different from the examples you saw? (tip: it's the `{`) Honestly, you got a *beautiful* error message, and the exact location.

Comment: Try this:  [document.ready shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3907527/475820).

Comment: This is just not how you call functions. Please review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pass an object to the ready (or try to pass it)

You have this

```
 $(document).ready{(function()};
```

You need this

```
 $(document).ready(function() { });
```

Comment: It's not that "You don't need to pass an object" at all.  It's just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var isSplash = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
 if(location.hash.length === 0) {
    location.hash="!/"+$('#content > ul > li').eq(2).attr('id');
 }
});
```