# missing ; before statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  getting an error on this, what have I missed?

My Code:

```
$function(){ 
            $(".product-add-link").on("click", BindAddProduct); 
        }
```

Firefox says:

> missing ; before statement

Chrome says:

> unexpected token {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot parenthesis :

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".product-add-link").on("click", BindAddProduct); 
});
```

The shortcut `$(function(){})` is an equivalent of `document.ready(function(){});`.

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907535/1437016) for further informations

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `$` accepts a `function as parameter`. You missed `(` for passing your function.

Please try below

```
$(function(){ 
  $(".product-add-link").on("click", BindAddProduct); 
 });
```